# App from IOS device back to xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

While finishing an Xcode project I made a stupid mistake...

I deleted the main view of my storyboard and ran the app on the simulator, which showed an empty screen. Then I tried reverting changes and had no success as the project gets saved every time it runs. (I didn't make snapshots)

I have a demo of a previous version of my app (before I made the mistake) in my iphone, is there a way I can retrieve it back into Xcode?

or any other suggestions?

Comment: If you are not using a version control like `git` or even snapshot feature of xCode, your only resort it to figure out what is now wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you have `.git` inside your project, you can just select the files you want to roll back from the project navigator. Then, right click on it. You will find `Source Control`-> `Discard Changes in Selected Files`.